# Where can I add try{...} code when I try to optimize init statement in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I find that there are some redundance code in Code A , It seems that I needn't to use init statement.

So I try to optimize it into Code B, but I don't know how to add `try {...}` in Code B, you know that it's necessary to write error into a log, how can I add `try{...} catch (e:Exception){...}` in Code B ? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
class DetailsHandler(mContext: Context = UIApp.instance) {

    var mJson: String by PreferenceTool(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.SavedJsonName), "")
    private var listofMDetail: MutableList<MDetail>?=null

    init {
        try{
            listofMDetail = myGson.fromJson<MutableList<MDetail>>(mJson) 
        }catch(e:Exception) {
            e.message?.let{ logError("Paser: "+it)}
        }
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class DetailsHandler(mContext: Context = UIApp.instance) {
    var mJson: String by PreferenceTool(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.SavedJsonName) , "")
    private var listofMDetail: MutableList<MDetail>?= myGson.fromJson<MutableList<MDetail>>(mJson)
}
```

**To voddan:**

Thanks!

`listofMDetail` maybe is null when it is from `myGson.fromJson(mJson)`

So I have to define `listofMDetail` as var if I need to use the fun `addDetail`. I need to assign `mutableListOf(aMDetail)` to `listofMDetail` when `listofMDetail` is null.

Do you have a better way?

```
fun addDetail(aMDetail:MDetail){
   if (listofMDetail==null){
       listofMDetail=mutableListOf(aMDetail)
   }else {
       listofMDetail?.add(aMDetail)
   }

    mJson =myGson.toJson(listofMDetail) //Save
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `try` block as an expression. Then you can make your `var` into `val`.

```
class DetailsHandler(mContext: Context = UIApp.instance) {

    val mJson: String by PreferenceTool(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.SavedJsonName), "")

    private val listofMDetail: MutableList<MDetail>? = 
        try{
            myGson.fromJson(mJson) 
        }catch(e:Exception) {
            e.message?.let{ logError("Paser: "+it)}
            null
        } 
}
```

Also, I would not recommend logging the exception and having null in `listofMDetail`. It will complicate all the other code that uses. Throwing the exception seems like a much more adequate solution:

```
    private val listofMDetail: MutableList<MDetail> = 
        try{
            myGson.fromJson(mJson) ?: mutableListOf()
        }catch(e:Exception) {
            e.message?.let{ logError("Paser: "+it)}
            throw RuntimeError(e)
        }
```

Somewhat refactored code:

```
    private val listofMDetail: MutableList<MDetail> = 
        try{
            myGson.fromJson(mJson) ?: mutableListOf()
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            logError("Can't find $mJson in $myGson; Error: ${e.message}")
            mutableListOf()
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! would you please see my added content in my question?

Comment: @HelloCW just do this logic with an empty mutable list on assignment. I did it with `?: mutableListOf()`, but other options are good as well

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

```
class DetailsHandler(mContext: Context = UIApp.instance) 
{
Private var listofMDetail: MutableList<MDetail> = mutableListOf()
var mJson: String by PreferenceTool(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.SavedJsonName) , "")
     try {
        listofMDetail: MutableList<MDetail>?= myGson.fromJson<MutableList<MDetail>>(mJson)
        }catch (e:Exception) 
        {  
         e.message?.let{ logError("Paser: "+it)}
        }

    }
```